# Saving an excel file in VBA loop

Tags: excel, loops, save, vba

I have created a macro which loops through a list of countries and this updates number on "Dash_eng". I can get the loop to work but part of the loop calls another macro which copies and saves "Dash_Eng") as an excel file

Both macro work when run independently of each other its just putting them together

Macro which loops though the country and calls the saving in excel macro

```
Sub ReportUpdate()    
Dim i As Integer, numrows As Integer
    Sheets("Text").Select        
    numrows = Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

     Range("O1").Select
     i = 1
     Do While i <= numrows
         ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnoffset:=4) = "X"
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
         Range("M1") = ActiveCell
         Call Send_to_PDF
         i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox "Dear Sir / Madam your base data has been refreshed and all other relivant formatting macros have been run"
End Sub
```

Saving macro

```
Sub Send_to_PDF()

Dim Ref As String

Dim St As String
Dim En As String
Dim Ex_Ref As String

FilePath = "P:\Hyundai\Hyundai GLOBAL\Country folders\EUROPE\A3 Ops reports"

Sheets("Dashboard - ENG").Select
Sheets("Dashboard - ENG").Copy


Cells.Select
Range("C1").Activate
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Ex_Ref = Sheets("Dashboard - Eng").Range("L1")
St = FilePath + "\Dashboard - ENG"
Ref = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now()), "yyyymm")
En = ".xlsx"


  ChDir FilePath
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=St & " " & " " & Ex_Ref & " " & Ref & En

  ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ( _
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 15\Theme Colors\Office 2007 - 2010.xml" _
        )


  ActiveWindow.Close
```

PS: I know its not sending it to PDF

Anyone any Ideas?

Comment: avoid `.Select`, `.ActiveWorkbook`, and `.Activate` at all costs! Refactor all your code to qualify all workbooks, sheets, and ranges (cells) to variables and work directly with them inside of `With End` blocks and you will probably fix your issue, or be able to better understand why its not working ... And now that I read it more, change `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` to `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` (and supply needed arguments)

Comment: Sorry if I caused any confusion this sheet USED to be exported as a PDF but NOW NEEDS to be saved as an excel sheet which is whats causing me the issue

Comment: did you refactor the code like I suggested? I am sure that will help solve the issue. Using ActiveSheet and ActiveWorkbook and jumping between them so much can cause a lot of unexpected problems?

Comment: No Scott I've not tried it yet but I'll give it go first thing Monday

Comment: Hi Scott I have to use active worksheet as the method I have to use to copy the excel tab create the active sheet in a randomly named file. I use the tab copy to new sheet method to create a copy of the dashboard  - Eng tab

Comment: Right. But that is the **only** place you absolutely need it. And even then, you can assign to a worksheet variable right after he copy method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just PDF the Sheet, you don't have to copy it.

for example

```
Sub PDFme()
    Dim dr As String
    Dim PDFnm As String
    Dim myFnm As String
    Dim PdfSH As Worksheet

    dr = "C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\"
    PDFnm = "MyPDF.pdf"
    myFnm = dr & PDFnm
    Set PdfSH = Sheets("Dashboard - ENG")

    PdfSH.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                              myFnm, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                              IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
                              True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to save it as excel, though I agree PDF would be FAR simpler

Comment: Didn't you want to save it as a PDF, I thought that was the whole issue. Possibly reword your question if that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thanks for the help I've fixed the issue.

It was not with the saving macro but the looping macro

Sub ReportUpdate()

Dim i As Integer, numrows As Integer

```
    **Sheets("Text").Select (**

    numrows = Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Range("O1").Select

    i = 1

     Do While i <= numrows

     Sheets("text").Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnoffset:=4) = "X"
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     Range("M1") = ActiveCell

              Save_2_Excel

    i = i + 1

    Loop


    MsgBox "Dear Sir / Madam your base data has been refreshed and all other relivant formatting macros have been run"
```

End Sub

The line is bold was all I added because the active cell in sheet raw needed to be reactivated before the loop began once more

PS: If you are copying this to loop through saving a file in excel add to the excel saving macro

ActiveWindow.Close False

This will close the new sheet without saving which is cool because this is the last instruction and the sheet is already saved